# How can I get Date object from string?

Tags: javascript

Why following code is not work ?

```
var date = new Date("31/01/2015"); // => return "Invalid Date"
alert(date);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fm3rnze5/

How can I get Date object from string ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date( Date.parse("2015/01/31") );
alert( date );
```

You need this format: YYYY/MM/DD. Then you can use Date.parse() https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse